# How do I change the Google Analytics Integration?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

I set up a project a year ago with an Integration to Google Analytics. When I revisited again recently I see that Google Analytics property no longer exists within my Google Analytics account.

I'd like to remove that property and replace it with a newly created GA4 property.

How do I change Google Analytics Integrations using the Firebase UI?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the Google Analytics property is no longer in your account is very strange. In any case, to use GA4 you have to create a new Google Analytics 4 Property and to use the code provided.

[GA4] Firebase integration: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9289234?hl=en

Note: the best practices, to date, suggest not to replace the old Property but to track in parallel to the old one and the new one (with the relative codes). Obviously, if you no longer find your old Property, the problem does not exist.

Comment: Yes, it was an old Mobile account that Google removed when they made the change to App & Web. Yes, i did create a new GA4 property. How do i associate it with my Firebase Project?

Comment: I edited the answer adding link to the documentation

Comment: How to change just Google Analytics property? my Firebase are already exist. Can "move property" or delete current GA to linked to new GA4?